# retrieve data from database in struts

Tags: java, struts

I am retrieving all databases data with struts framework,code is working good.

i just put list(Array list) of data in request for JSP(as above code).i know we can get data with logic tag library but i don't have much idea of that.and is it okay to put data in request?and how we can retrive data with logic library?or any other way?

```
        HashMap hm =null;
        List list = new ArrayList();
        String uname="";
        int no=0;
        while(rs.next())
        {
            uname=rs.getString(1);
            no = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(2));
            hm=new HashMap();
            hm.put("name", uname);
            hm.put("number", no);

            list.add(hm);

        }

        request.setAttribute("myList",list);
```

jsp page.

```
                   <%
                        try
                        {
                            DataForm d= new DataForm();
                            HashMap hm;
                            List list = new ArrayList();
                            if(request.getAttribute("myList")!=null)
                                list=(List)request.getAttribute("myList");
                            else
                                out.print("No Data Found..");

                             for(int i=1;i<list.size();i++)
                             {
                                hm=(HashMap)list.get(i);

                                %><tr> <td><%out.println(hm.get("name"));%></td>
                                 <td><%out.println(hm.get("number"));%></td></tr><%
                            }
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
                    %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic tags are not used to retrieve the data: They're used to implement some logic in the JSP without using scriptlets, which are considered bad practice.

It's indeed the job of the controller (the Struts action), not to retrieve the data from the database, but to call objects that will, and to put the list of objects in the request in order for the view to display them.

The struts logic tag, however, are almost all deprecated in favor of the JSP EL and the JSTL. Your scriptlet code could be replaced by the following lines:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${myList == null}">
        No Data Found.
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:forEach var="element" items="${myList}">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${element.name}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${element.number}"/></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Which is much more readable and escapes the data correctly.

I would also use objects instead of HashMaps to hold your data. Java is an OO language. Use objects and encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you are trying to do, I must say that you are not making effective use of a HashMap.

A Hashmap is used to store  pairs so that you are able to retrieve the values using a key fast ~ O(1). Keys are unique in a hashmap. If you try to store multiple  pairs one after the other using the same key, the data will be be overwritten and in the end you will see only the last pair.

In this example, you are using a HashMap just as a container to hold "name" and "number" and hence I don't see a real need for the hashMap at all.

This is what you can do:

Define a class that holds name and number:

```
class Data
{
    private String name;
    public int uNo;
    public Data(String name, int uNo)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.uNo = uNo;
    }
    public getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
    public getUNo()
    {
        return this.uNo;
    }
}
```

Your Java Code :

```
List<Data> list = new ArrayList<Data>();
while(rs.next())
{
    String uname=rs.getString(1);
    int no = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(2));
    list.add(new Data(uname, no));
}
request.setAttribute("myList",list);
```

Your Jsp Code:

```
<%
    try
    {
        DataForm d= new DataForm();
        List<Data> list = new ArrayList<Data>();
        if(request.getAttribute("myList")!=null)
        {
           list = (List<Data>)request.getAttribute("myList");
           for(Data data in list)
           {
               %><tr><td><%out.println(data.getName());%></td>
                     <td><%out.println(data.getUNo());%></td></tr><%
           }
        }
        else
        {
           out.print("No Data Found..");
        }
     }
     catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
%>
```

Now, coming to the **Logic Tag Library**.

This is what you will need to make the following modifications:

i) In your jsp, you may do this:
Add these lines in the beginning of your jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic"%>
```

Use these to write your data:

```
<logic:present name="myList">
  <logic:iterate name="myList" id="myListId">
     <tr>
          <td><bean:write name="myListId" property="name"/></td>
          <td><bean:write name="myListId" property="uNo"/></td>
     <tr>
  </logic:iterate>
</logic:present>
<logic:notPresent name="myList">
    No Data found.
</logic:notPresent>
```

Ideally, I would have used JSTL to show the list of User/No.

I have not tested this code. But it delivers what I have in mind.